# Symfony2 - assets do not load

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony, assets

Today again something doesn't work in my symfony2 test project. Now i'm trying to use some assets like .css file and images.

What did i do so far?
Bundle name is MyValleyBundle so in AppKernel.php bundle is registered:

```
new My\ValleyBundle\MyValleyBundle(),
```

I did put files respectively css to css, images to images and so on, to this folder:
src/My/ValleyBundle/Resources/public/
then i did execute this command:
php app/console assets:install web
in index.html.twig i've placed properly these two lines:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<img src="{{ asset('images/file.png') }}" alt="some image" />
```

Just in case i recursively chmoded all files and folders in symfony2 folder with 775 permission, in desperation i tried also 777.

Output? When i open website it displays h1, h2 and other text related tags executed from .twig file but totally ignores anything what i tried to load as assets.

Also tried other browser, cleaning cache, restarting server.

How to make assets being used? They are not in use at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asset files need to be qualified by a bundle - assets:install installs them in an appropriately named subdirectory of /web/bundles:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/myvalley/css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/myvalley/images/file.png') }}" alt="some image" />
```

If you look for your files within the web directory you will see this directory structure. Note that the assets:install command outputs the location it is copying the files for each bundle to.

Comment: Is bundles/myvalley definitely the location of your bundle files in the web directory? have you looked / taken it from the output of the assets/install command? because what you have in your original question is definitely never going to work.

Comment: Also - did you try this before or after I edited? - because there was a mistake in my initial post.

Comment: Finally (sorry!) you should include everything you have tried in your original post so that answerers are not wasting their time and have the opportunity to point out possible errors in what you have already tried.

Comment: Yes, your edited lines helped me, thanks! This is how finally looks line which works: <img src="{{ asset('bundles/myvalley/images/image.jpg') }}" alt="some image" />

Answer (score 0):

enter the command

```
app/console assets:install
```

in your projects maindirectory with the console. This will copy your files from the **src/AppBundle/Recourses/public/** to the **web/bundles/app/** directory

Comment: I did this, still the same. No css applied, nor images displayed.